# 2 separate legends for the same aesthetic ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get 2 separate legends for different groups of variables when using "facet_wrap" in ggplot 2. Basically I want to break up the legend into 2, one with "Yes/No" and one with "Sometimes/Never" and have each one close to those variables that they correspond with.

```
Answer<-c("Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never","Sometimes","Never","Never")

var<-c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50),rep("C",50),rep("D",50),rep("E",50),rep("F",50),rep("G",50),rep("H",50),rep("I",50))

cat<-c(rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10),
rep("red",10),rep("blue",10),rep("green",10),rep("yellow",10),rep("orange",10))

df2<-tibble(Answer,var,cat)


layout2<-"
AB##
CDE#
FGHI"
  
df2$Answer<-factor(df2$Answer,levels=c("Yes","No","Sometimes","Never"))

ggplot(df2,aes(fill=Answer,x=cat))+
  geom_bar(stat="count",position=position_dodge())+
 facet_manual(~var,scales="free_x",design=layout2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue4","lightblue","thistle2","darkorchid4"))+
  labs(x="",y="Frequency")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic. To make this work you have to use two `geom_bar` layers, one for your `A` and `B` panels containing the `Yes/No` categories and one for the other panels.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = cat)) +
  geom_bar(
    data = ~ subset(df2, var %in% c("A", "B")), aes(fill = Answer),
    stat = "count", position = position_dodge()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue4", "lightblue")) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_bar(
    data = ~ subset(df2, !var %in% c("A", "B")), aes(fill = Answer),
    stat = "count", position = position_dodge()
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "foo", values = c("thistle2", "darkorchid4")) +
  facet_manual(~var, scales = "free_x", design = layout2) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Frequency") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to put them on the bottom or top of each group of graphs?